# CUPS Passcode PIN

Tags: networking, printing, cups-lpd

I'm trying to set up a networked printer (a Konica Minolta Bizhub c558) that uses a four digit pin to authorize printing. I've set up the printer (using ipp://)  and edited the `printers.conf` to try and hard code the PIN, but it isn't working.

The printer worked as expected before the PIN was introduced. I just need to add the authorization somehow.

CUPS seems to expect a user and a passphrase, but for me there is just the pin.

I've tried to set the `printers.conf` file to "negotiate" so that it will bring up a dialog for the PIN, but it won't accept a blank user.

What am I to do?

Comment: What kind of printer is it? Is it managed, or do you send print jobs to the printer directly? [Edit] your post to include as much detail about your printer as possible.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect your question, @vidarlo.

Comment: The print jobs are just sent directly to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [Open issue](https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/4969) since 2017 and is still not implemented.

Therefore, unless you program the functionality itself it doesn't look like this will be available soon.

### Sorry! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯